# Highlighting a cell if it contains one of strings in a range

Tags: google-sheets

Using conditional formatting I wanted to know if it was possible to do the following:

I have a sheet, bad_data, with lets says columns B, F, and K, that contain bad data. Each cell has a string of length 6 (although I do not think it matters in this case).  Columns B, F, and K  all have different amount of rows, and I'll probably be adding to each as time goes on.

I have another sheet(within the same workbook, let's call this sheet "records") where I keep certain records of things.  In this sheet, there are columns that could contain the previously mentioned bad data, lets use column M as the example.

I am having difficulty coming up with a formula that highlights a cell if it contains any of the strings in columns B, F, and K, ie: look in a range of cells, for all values in a range of cells

I've been able to come up with ways highlight a cell of they are identical, eg: if M10 = 123456 and B= 123456 but I also need to highlight if M10 = "123456,78910,111213".

Eventually id like to extract the matching string and write it to another cell (probably using the regex function in sheets) or highlight the matching string within the cell, is this even possible?

I could easily come up with ways to do this in python, perl, bash, ect....but I figured it'd be easier for users that are not code savvy to maintain in spreadsheet.

Maybe I am overthinking this, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting based on custom formula with `regexmatch`, where the regex is built out of the specified columns. Here is an example with column B:

```
=regexmatch(M10, "\b(" & join("|", filter($B:$B, len($B:$B))) & ")\b")
```

`filter($B:$B, len($B:$B))` takes nonempty cells in column B. They are joined as regex alternatives and wrapped in word boundaries (in case you want to enforce those).

Same with several columns, just join the results of joins:

```
& join("|", filter($B:$B, len($B:$B))) & "|" & join("|", filter($F:$F, len($F:$F))) & "|" & join("|", filter($K:$K, len($K:$K)))
```

By the way, if your strings are indeed numeric like "123456", they should be formatted as plain text for the regexmatch to treat them as strings.

> extract the matching string and write it to another cell

Can be done using `regexextract` with exactly the same arguments as `regexmatch` above.

> highlight the matching string within the cell

Impossible. Partial formatting for cell content exists, but only for manual edits. It cannot be applied by formulas or scripts.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've managed to get the match working for a whole column (replaced M10 for $M:$M so it checks all of M).  Would I need to use any other functions if $B:$B is in another sheet(not workbook)? its not recognizing my named range or, Sheet1!A:A format.  Also, Im a bit confused by the regextract still, while i understand the parameters are the same, where does it output the matches? on the same cell it finds it? would I have to apply the formula to an empty column and then the matches will generate?

Comment: nevermind, figured out regextract and referencing :)